# Can't install graphics driver on Asus A44H with AMD Radeon HD 6470M

Tags: windows-7, ati-mobility-radeon

I have an Asus A44H laptop with a AMD Radeon HD 6470M.

When I'm trying to install the graphics driver, it says that my computer does not contain a proper graphics adapter.

Comment: Which drivers are you trying to install? What is the exact error message you're getting? Can you maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: I see you're not using an nVidia graphics card and you're having problems... Coincidence?

Comment: @slhck i'am trying to install the AMD catalyst mobility but it shows message that my laptop does't contain proper graphic adapter

Comment: @naquib: Are you absolutely sure that your model has that graphics chipset? Googling that model I can only see versions that have integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: @James i'am 100% sure...when i checked my device manager, it shows the correct graphics chipset..

Comment: @naquib Can you post a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Laptop manufacturers don't always hook up graphics chipsets exactly the way the chipset manufacturer expect. This may require you to use the driver provided by the laptop manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you chose the Notebook drivers.

64 Bit Win 7/Vista

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx

32 Bit

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-32.aspx

Comment: i  already download it,which is 64 bit win 7..but the error message keep appear...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ASUS website and use the drivers that they provide for your laptop, they will be optimised to take into account how the graphics chip is used by the laptop and the type of display it is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

try this ones here:

http://www.guru3d.com/files_details/amd_catalyst_13_1_whql_download.html

just be sure to choose the right ones, that is, the MOBILITY version, and either 32 or 64 bit version.

hope it helps, those worked for me in a win 8 (updated from 7) HP dv6-6c85la with a radeon hd 6770m (hp names it as a 7690m xt)